# AudioContext audio stuttering in Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I'm using AudioContext in an ionic app to stream raw PCM audio data to a backend, the resulting audio is has a lot of stutters if the client is google chrome on android. All other android browsers work fine (tried firefox, edge and samsung browser) also all desktop browsers work fine including google chrome.

```
startRecording() { 
    navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
        audio: {
            echoCancellation: true,
        },
    })
    .then((s) => {
    this.stream = s;
    this.record();
    this.startRecordingStream(this.stream);
});

startRecordingStream(s) {
    let audioContext = new AudioContext();
    this.scriptProcessor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 2, 1);
    let input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(s);
    input.connect(this.scriptProcessor);
    this.scriptProcessor.connect(audioContext.destination);
    this.scriptProcessor.addEventListener("audioprocess", this.streamAudioData);
}
```

I tried logging the buffer on the client side, it has zeros scattered all over it in a periodic manner.

I have also tested this example https://mozdevs.github.io/MediaRecorder-examples/filter-and-record-live-audio.html on my device, it uses audioContext and it seems to suffer from the same audio stutter on google chrome on android.

Is there any walkarounds to this?